# battery status command for Ratpoison on ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have begun [Ratpoison](http://www.nongnu.org/ratpoison/) as a tiling window manager for my ubuntu laptop.
One thing I have noticed is that there is no support for battery alerts leading me to completely draining my laptop battery before realizing that the battery was low.

Thus I performed the following in a terminal window.

- [alias bat='upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0| grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage"'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69556/how-to-check-battery-status-using-terminal)
- ratpoison -c "echo $(bat)"

Even when I execute

- ratpoison -c "echo $(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0| grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage")"

I get satisfactory results by seeing the battery status in the [message popup](http://www.nongnu.org/ratpoison/doc/The-Status-Bar.html) of ratpoison.

However when I execute this single command using the [exec command](http://www.nongnu.org/ratpoison/doc/Other-Commands.html#Other-Commands) in ratpoison
I get the message

/bin/sh -c "exec ratpoison -c "echo $(bat)"" finished (1)

**What is causing this behaviour?**

Is it because I am invoking the ratpoison -c command and also the bat alias? The docs say that exec is for a single command.?

Any help is appreciated.

**Also**

typing alert in the terminal makes an alert popup show.
doing exec alert in ratpoison shows a similar message that /bin/sh -c "alert" finished (127)

**What are the numbers in brackets?**

Answer (score 1):

Ok...that was silly. For other lost souls.

The number enclosed in the brackets is apparently the exit code if the script you specify exits with a non zero code.

This script finally worked.

```
#!/bin/bash
batstat=$(upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0| grep -E "state|to\ full|percentage")
ratpoison -c "echo $batstat"
```

and using

```
bind B exec ~./rat_bat_stat.sh
```

in the ~/.ratpoisonrc file I was able to get this up and running.